# MySQL Limit with WHERE IN clause

Tags: mysql

This is a little different that the solutions I've found thus far. I have a relationship between users and companies (users has a company_id column). I need to create a query that get the first 5 users per company. The following gets the first 3 users total:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE company_id IN (1, 2, 3, ...) LIMIT 3;
```

Rather than the first 3 user per company. Right now I'm looping through the companies in PHP and and running a query that grabs the user by the company's ID with a `LIMIT 3`, but it's possible to have 100s of companies, so this is not performant at all. Is there a way for me to get the first 'n' users of a list of companies if I have their ids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, the easiest way is probably to use variables:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM (SELECT u.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = company_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := company_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      FROM users u CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @c := -1, @rn := 0) params
      WHERE u.company_id IN (1, 2, 3, ...)
      ORDER BY u.company_id
     ) u
WHERE seqnum <= 3;
```

Note:  SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no such thing as "the first three", unless a column specifies the ordering.  If you have such a column, then include it as a second key in the `ORDER BY`.

Explanation of the variables.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `SELECT`.  Hence, a variable should not be referenced in one expression and then set in another -- you don't know which will be run first.  The above formulation is a way of setting the variables in a single expression while doing the right thing.

Comment: interesting that you used `if(@c := company_id, 1, 1)` to set @c

Comment: @Fabricator . . . I added an explanation.